# Azure Kinect Sensor SDK on NVIDIA Jetson AGX Orin

Tags: docker, nvidia-jetson, azurekinect

Is it possible to use the Azure Kinect Sensor SDK (k4a-tools) on the NVIDIA Jetson AGX Orin Development Kit? It is quite difficult to find any docker images or other solutions.

I tried to search for instructions and docker images.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to look into the jetson-containers docker images created with Dockerfiles especially for NVIDIA/jetson products. Link : [jetson-containers](https://github.com/dusty-nv/jetson-containers)